# Why can I call Form.Close() if it's not a static method

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

Can someone explain this to me?

In Visual Studio 2010, create a VB.net Windows Forms App. Add 2 forms: Form1 and Form2. In the Form1 Load event type Form2.Close(). Now if we look in the method definition Close() is not a static (shared) method. So how is this possible to compile or to work at run time.

Furthermore, do the same thing in C# and Form2.Close(); doesn't compile.

What's going on? Why is this possible in VB.net and what is actually happening when that line of code is executed?

Comment: This is what happens when Microsoft puts the `MS Access` developers in charge of `VB.NET` to make it more appealing to the `VB6`/`VBA` crowd. Disaster ensues ...

Comment: @ja72 surely the point of anything called "VB.x" is to have at least some appeal to VB6 & VBA users. That said, I loathed this feature in VB6 and its continuation was another reason to learn C# instead, so I suppose it only appealed to some of the VB crowd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've discovered a VB.NET-ism called "default instance".

The compiler is actually emitting this:

```
My.Forms.Form2.Close();
```

There is a nice [writeup of that feature here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/07/vbnet-default-form-instances.html):

> The default instance is an object of that type that the VB application framework creates and manages for you.
>
> ...
>
> If you use the default instance then you don’t need to invoke a constructor explicitly. You simply access the default instance directly via the My.Forms object

Comment: I love the reasoning behind this feature: *One of the main goals of VB has always been to provide power while make programming as easy as possible for as many people as possible. The introduction of default form instances is in furtherance of that goal. Many people new to OOP use objects in VB.NET but they don’t really comprehend them properly.* What a lovely reason to introduce implicit lazy-instantiated singletons: many people new to OOP, don't really know OOP, so let's introduce another exceptional feature.

Comment: Exactly what happened in this case. My client barely understands what he is doing and has very little knowledge of OOP. Yet he managed to do the complete opposite of what he was trying to do: he increased the memory used by the program, when he was trying to decrease it.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that VB creates an automatic instance of the form if you just reference them by name, which could lead to unintended consequences at runtime if it isn't caught.

There is no setting that I have found to prevent this from happening.

However, you can "break" this behavior at compile time by changing the scope of the default constructor from Public to Friend or by removing the default constructor and adding one that requires a parameter. Either or these changes will disable the automatic form references.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, you cannot call `Form2.Close();` when `Form2` is only a class type. VB.NET, however, creates a property with the same name behind the scenes, and so you are really calling `Close` on an instance of `Form2`. You can do the same in C#, if you manually create such a property. It looks like a static method call, but it isn't.

Comment: -1. This is a compiler emitting a call to the default instance using the VB application framework.

Comment: Take a look at the generated parts of the executable, using ILSpy or similar. It's implemented as a property.

Comment: it is a property, that's just an implementation detail, saying it's a property doesn't explain how it works. It's a property on a compiler generated type called MyForms. In addition; VB.NET doesn't give any hint that you are calling `Close` on a property. It looks like a static call.

Comment: Yes, except for the name of the compiler-generated type it is implemented on (which I didn't mention), isn't that what I said?